# How to calculate weighted mean using mutate_at in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, weighted-average

I have a dataframe ("df") with a number of columns that I would like to estimate the weighted means of, weighting by population (df$Population), and grouping by commuting zone (df$cz).

This is the list of columns I would like to estimate the weighted means of:

```
 vlist = c("Public_Welf_Total_Exp", "Welf_Cash_Total_Exp", "Welf_Cash_Cash_Assist", "Welf_Ins_Total_Exp","Total_Educ_Direct_Exp", "Higher_Ed_Total_Exp", "Welf_NEC_Cap_Outlay","Welf_NEC_Direct_Expend", "Welf_NEC_Total_Expend", "Total_Educ_Assist___Sub", "Health_Total_Expend", "Total_Hospital_Total_Exp", "Welf_Vend_Pmts_Medical","Hosp_Other_Total_Exp","Unemp_Comp_Total_Exp", "Unemp_Comp_Cash___Sec", "Total_Unemp_Rev", "Hous___Com_Total_Exp", "Hous___Com_Construct")
```

This is the code I have been using:

```
 df = df %>% group_by(cz) %>% mutate_at(vlist, weighted.mean(., df$Population))
```

I have also tried:

```
 df = df %>% group_by(cz) %>% mutate_at(vlist, function(x) weighted.mean(x, df$Population))
```

As well as tested the following code on only 2 columns:

```
 df = df %>% group_by(cz) %>% mutate_at(vars(Public_Welf_Total_Exp, Welf_Cash_Total_Exp), weighted.mean(., df$Population))
```

However, everything I have tried gives me the following error, even though there are no NAs in any of my variables:

```
 Error in weighted.mean.default(., df$Population) : 
   'x' and 'w' must have the same length
```

I understand that I could do the following estimation using lapply, but I don't know how to group by another variable using lapply. I would appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Try taking out the `df$` in front of `Population` in your `weighted.mean` call.

Comment: When I try that, I get the following error: "Error in weighted.mean.default(., Population) : 
  object 'Population' not found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot to unpack here...

1. Probably you mean `summarise` instead of `mutate`, because with `mutate` you would just replicate your result for each row.
2. `mutate_at` and `summarise_at` are subseeded and you should use `across` instead.
3. the reason why your code wasn't working was because you did not write your function as a formula (you did not add `~` at the beginning), also you were using `df$Population` instead of `Population`. When you write `Population`, `summarise` knows you're talking about the column `Population` which, at that point, is grouped like the rest of the dataframe. When you use `df$Population` you are calling the column of the original dataframe without grouping. Not only it is wrong, but you would also get an error because the length of the variable you are trying to average and the lengths of the weights provided by `df$Population` would not correspond.

Here is how you could do it:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   group_by(cz) %>% 
   summarise(across(vlist, weighted.mean, Population),
             .groups = "drop")
```

If you really need to use `summarise_at` (and probably you are using an old version of `dplyr` [lower than 1.0.0]), then you could do:

```
df %>%
   group_by(cz) %>% 
   summarise_at(vlist, ~weighted.mean(., Population)) %>%
   ungroup()
```

---

I considered `df` and `vlist` like the following:

```
vlist <- c("Public_Welf_Total_Exp", "Welf_Cash_Total_Exp", "Welf_Cash_Cash_Assist", "Welf_Ins_Total_Exp","Total_Educ_Direct_Exp", "Higher_Ed_Total_Exp", "Welf_NEC_Cap_Outlay","Welf_NEC_Direct_Expend", "Welf_NEC_Total_Expend", "Total_Educ_Assist___Sub", "Health_Total_Expend", "Total_Hospital_Total_Exp", "Welf_Vend_Pmts_Medical","Hosp_Other_Total_Exp","Unemp_Comp_Total_Exp", "Unemp_Comp_Cash___Sec", "Total_Unemp_Rev", "Hous___Com_Total_Exp", "Hous___Com_Construct")
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(length(vlist) * 100), ncol = length(vlist)))
names(df) <- vlist
df$cz <- rep(letters[1:10], each = 10)
df$Population <- runif(100)
```

Comment: thank you - the solution works, but more importantly your explanation is incredibly helpful!

Comment: one more follow-up Q: what does ".groups = "drop"" do?

Comment: in  `dplyr >= 1.0.0`, you don't need to write `ungroup` at the end of a `summarise statement`. You can specify how to treat the existing groups directly in the `summarise`. By writing `.groups = "drop"` you're asking to `summarise` to remove the groups you created with `group_by`. If you don't specify it you will get an annoying message like the following: `summarise() ungrouping output (override with .groups argument)`